# Does nodejs global variable bind to "module" function, how to assign?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, module, this

Another post here explains that "Node wraps module's code into a function", and gave an explanation "https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper"

But I am still confused, I have following snippet:

```
var n = 'my'
module.a='k'
console.log(module.a);
console.log(module.n);
```

Using nodejs, it prints out

```
k
undefined
```

Question: if script level variables like 'n' is binded to function scope of nodejs "module", why 'module.n' doesn't exist?

Thanks.

Comment: Nowhere it says that local scoped variables become bound to the `module` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you place your code and the wrapper function in the same picture, you'll get it:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
    var n = 'my'
    module.a='k'
    console.log(module.a); // k
    console.log(module.n); // undefined
});
```

you see that `module.n` is undefined because there's no code line that would set a value for it.

There's no magic that would cause "script level variables like 'n' get bound to 'module'".